# why DCL use volatile ,not use final?i code run same effect

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, final, volatile

```
package test1;

import java.util.Random;

public class OneInstanceService {
    // use volatile or final,them has same effect,
    // but difference volatile or final in DCL demo?
    public int i_am_has_state;

    private static OneInstanceService test;

    private OneInstanceService() {
        i_am_has_state = new Random().nextInt(200) + 1;
    }

    public static OneInstanceService getTest1() {
        if (test == null) {
            synchronized (OneInstanceService.class) {
                if (test == null) {
                    test = new OneInstanceService();
                }
            }
        }
        return test;
    }

    public static void reset() {
        test = null;
    }

}


//----------------------------------------
package test1;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        for (;;) {
            CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
            CountDownLatch end = new CountDownLatch(100);
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                Thread t1 = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            latch.await();
                            OneInstanceService one = OneInstanceService.getTest1();
                            if (one.i_am_has_state == 0) {
                                System.out.println("one.i_am_has_state == 0 process exit");
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                            end.countDown();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                t1.start();
            }
            latch.countDown();
            end.await();
            OneInstanceService.reset();
        }
    }
}
```

only use :

```
public int i_am_has_state;
```

run result is :

```
System.out.println("one.i_am_has_state == 0 process exit");
System.exit(0);
```

but modify code bottom:

```
volatile public int i_am_has_state;
```

or

```
final public int i_am_has_state;
```

no run bottom code:

```
System.out.println("one.i_am_has_state == 0 process exit");
System.exit(0);
```

i question is :
DCL use final ok
DCL use final volatile ok

so
in DCL final and volatile difference?

thank you very much !

Comment: I think you're getting mixed up. DCL requires that `test` be volatile, unless `OneInstanceService` is thread-safe.

Comment: hi shmosel,but i test final thread-save too.final and volatile them has no reorder effect?

Comment: @Gaohongyan You can walk across the street without looking both ways and not get hit by a car. That doesn't mean it's safe.

Comment: You are confused. The DCL here has exactly nothing to do with `i_am_has_state`. It uses the `test` variable.

Answer (score 0):

final and volatile cannot go together because they are purposefully opposite.

either you have a static field initialized  once upon class init:

```
static final Object x;
static {
    x = ...
}
```

or you have a volatile static field that multiple thread can race to set (your case).

It must be volatile for the double check idiom to work (with the new volatile semantic since jdk 1.5). Since then, the volatile has memory barriers preventing reordering of instructions involving other variables, which somehow (I can't recall that stuff now...) makes the ugly DCL work again... but doesn't make it less ugly.

(I never needed to use the DCL; without DCL, synchronization is still essentially uncontended because the `if(x==null)` is so fast.)

Answer (score -1):

thank all, bottom not answer.

I modify code:

```
package test1;

import java.util.Random;

public class OneInstanceService {
    final public int i_am_has_state;

    volatile private static OneInstanceService test;

    private OneInstanceService() {
        i_am_has_state = new Random().nextInt(200) + 1;
    }

    public static OneInstanceService getTest1() {
        if (test == null) {
            synchronized (OneInstanceService.class) {
                if (test == null) {
                    test = new OneInstanceService();
                }
            }
        }
        return test;
    }

    public static void reset() {
        test = null;
    }

}
```

Just had a sudden inspiration, the code is so perfect? I think I'm really getting mixed up.

shmosel:Forgive me for not formatting code and hightline, thank you very much.